# Expiration date for some database entries

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to set an expiration on DB entries. I've set the field to `datetime` and entered some values manually through MySQL

I take the value from the table and convert it to `strtotime()`. then I get the current time using `strtotime("now")`; or `time()`; they seemed to return the same value.

I then take the future date(the one from the db) and with if statement check if its smaller then current time if so I set it as expired. if it's still bigger then current time I return how much time left..

Here is the code for that:

```
$time_left = "";
$value['ex_date'] = '2012-11-22 18:17:33';// this is whats in the DB now.
$future_time = strtotime($value['ex_date']);
$now_time = strtotime('now');

if($deal_end < $now_time){
    $time_left = 'Expired';
}else{
    $seconds = $future_time - $now_time;
    $days = floor($seconds / 86400);
    $seconds %= 86400;
    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $seconds %= 3600;
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    $seconds %= 60;

    if($days >= 1) {$time_left .= "D:$day ";}
    if($hours >= 1) {$time_left .= "H:$hours ";}
    if($minutes >= 1) {$time_left .= "M:$minutes ";}
    if($seconds >= 1) {$time_left .= "S:$seconds ";}
```

For some reason the above doesn't work well. its like there is some time gap.

my question is: is there a way to check server time vs database time ?

because the `strtotime('now');` time seems different then current timestemp by like 2/3 hours for some reason.

Comment: 2-3 hour offset... Hmm... timezones? Did you set the timezone in PHP and/or your system and/or the database to the same value? Also: `strtotime('now')` is the same as `time()`.

Comment: I did not change anything in the php its a plugin i am building for WP.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two other approaches:
a. Select from the database rows that did not expire yet adding the logic to the query itself
b. run cron/mysql schedule every minute that will clear the database entries that had expired

`SELECT * from TABLE where X = Y and NOW() < expiredField`

---

Besides, PHP has a built in class just for the operations with date you are trying to perform.
It's called `DateTime`.

```
$dt = new DateTime('2012-11-22 18:17:33');
$dtNow = new DateTime();

$interval = $dtNow->diff($dt); // php.net/DateInterval
if($interval->invert) 
    echo 'expired';
else 
    echo $interval->format('%m month, %d days, %h hours, %s seconds');
```

---

**To your original question**

Checking the server time is
`echo time();`
Checking database time is
`SELECT NOW();`

Comment: I tried using DateTime but i think the php on my server is a bit old(not sure)

Comment: It's available with php 5.3 and higher. Check your php version.

Comment: 5.2.17 is the php version BTW so thats a no go for `DateTime()`;

Comment: See the answer to your question in the last part of the question and confirm times are equal on your PHP machine and on the MySQL server.

Comment: It shouldn't. Most likely you are reading it incorrectly in PHP. Try to run it in `phpmyadmin`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find server(linux) time zone using following at command line:

```
$ date +%Z
```

Or following in php:

```
$ echo system('date +%Z');
```

In php you can use `date_default_timezone_get` function.

Most probably your `system` and `php` timezones will be different.

You can change `php` timezone by using `date_default_timezone_set` [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: Does `time()`; returns my computer time? as i understand it returns server's time

Comment: It always returns server time, not your computer. At server its calculated by adjusting the difference of php timezone and server timezone if both are not same.

Answer (score 0):

In-case anyone is curious about how i solved it:

```
$result = mysql_query("select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;");
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
$DB_now = $row['CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'];



$deal_end = strtotime($value['ex_date']);
$now_time = strtotime($DB_now);
```

I just use database's current timestamp as "now"
Not sure if that's the best solution but it works